# NameError: name 'Bank' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

A class to handle deposits & withdraws in a bank.

```
import sys

class Bank(object):

    #to initialize name & balance instance vars
    def __init__(self, name, balance=0.0):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance

    #to add deposit amount to balance
    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
        return self.balance    

    #to deduct withdrawal amount from balance
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if amount >self.balance:
            print("Balance amount is less, so no withdrawl.")    
        else:
            self.balance -= amount
        return self.balance

#using the bank class create an account with the given name & balance 0.00
name = input('Enter name: ') 
b = Bank(name)  #this is instance of bank class

#repeat continuously till choice is 'e' or 'E'.
while(True):
    print ("d -Deposit, w -withdraw, e -Exiting")
    choice = input("Your choice: ")
    if choice == 'e' or choice == 'E':
        sys.exit()
    #amount for deposit or withdraw
    amt = float(input ("Enter amount: "))   

    #do the transaction
    if choice == 'd' or choice == 'D':
        print("Balance after deposit: ", b.deposit(amt))
    elif choice == 'w' or choice == 'W':
        print("Balance after withdraw: ", b.withdraw(amt))
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/code_files/bank_class.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Bank(object):
  File "d:/code_files/bank_class.py", line 25, in Bank
    b = Bank(name)  #this is instance of bank class
NameError: name 'Bank' is not defined
```

Can someone let me know what is missing?

Comment: Where do you write script of ```Bank``` class? to help you, we need more related information about your code

Comment: I tried your code, it works with no errors

Comment: Where's the Error, I don't see any error in the code, it is running perfectly fine in my system

Comment: Looking at the traceback, I suspect that the indentation was not correct and caused the error. If the line `b=Bank(name)` is at top level it should be fine executing the program.

Comment: The code works and does not raise error. You might not be importing or calling it correctly.

Comment: Thanks all, it was an indentation error.